# DexException: Cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For some unknown reason my app suddenly won't build from Android Studio.

I'm keep getting

```
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/martynas/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output
...
...
...
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

While the same application is built successfully from command line.
I've checked method references count and it's way below the dreaded 64k.

I'm using AS 0.8.11 now.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Try to add this line on your project.properties**

dex.force.jumbo=true

Which increment the limit for strings in a dex files. And your project will probably compile.

**Note :** Also with jumbo set, the is another limit of 64K only for methods in an single dex. If you get this limit in the future , you will need to remove some dependencies.

**Update - Google Play Services 6.5 (12-08-14)**

With version 6.5 Google finally unbundled the Google Play Services. So from now on it'll be possible to selectively compile the APIs into your executable.

**Example :**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+'
```

For all the other individual Google Play Services APIs check this [page on d.android.com.](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split)

Update (21-04-2015) : 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Adding to `project.properties` did not work so I updated my gradle build script as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320088/android-build-dex-jumbo-mode-in-gradle

Comment: I did both solutions: adding dex.force.jumbo property and dexOptions but I'm still receiving the same error. Another option?

Comment: @juancho,Check : https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split

Comment: Thanks @HareshChhelana. For some reason it started to work.. but I really didn't do anything special. I have some coworkers who are compiling the project without this options, but now it's working for me. Thanks!

Comment: instead of compiling the entire Google Play Services, i found using the 'base' bundle to be useful, to stay below the 65K dex limit:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'`

Comment: The "compile" configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by "implementation" or "api"

Answer (score 245):

Set the jumboMode property in build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

}
```

I also found this useful: [Showing dex method count by package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17098651/2770898).

Comment: Thanks! It works for me too. But what does this "jumboMode" mean?

Comment: @yital9 you can learn more about jumbo mode here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30517283/4034572

Comment: please explain the reason for this block

Comment: I added this inside debug build type alone as the release build goes fine, because of proguard. The debug build went fine after this modification. Is this fine?

Comment: Where is this file build.gradle? Inside the platform directory? Since I am on Ionic project. But I don't want to mess with the platform directory, what else could be done?

Comment: This works for me. Note that the build.gradle to be changed should be the module that throws com.android.dex.DexException.

Answer (score 54):

This works for me. I was getting `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 66636 into a non-jumbo instruction!`

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}
```

If this isn't working, you might have reached method reference limit in dex which is a different issue. You need to use either multidex or proGuard.

Comment: It's work for me. Thanks!!!  but what is 'jumboMode' ? Can you please explain me? @Sayooj

Answer (score 13):

This is a bug in the merger when the dex files that are being merged have more than 65536 strings. The new index can't fit in a const-string instruction, and the dex merger doesn't support changing instructions if they are different sizes, so it can't be widened to a const-string/jumbo instruction.This was fixed in jb-mr1 by adding a new option: --force-jumbo.This bug can be fixed by adding `"dex.force.jumbo=true"` to the project.properties.

Comment: @DeepakSharma You have to clean your project after enabling jumboMode

Answer (score -1):

With latest Android Studio and flag "force jumbo" checked on Android Studio compiler settings, this problem disappear.

Comment: If it's possible, add some details in your answer, plz.