# Got Error When Build APK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

When I create an Apk in android studio like Build ->Build APK, I encountered the following error.

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:<br>
Cause: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 68909 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

When I add the below code in android manifest

```
  android {
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
}
```

}

Then error is fixed but apk is big file size

Comment: what are you trying to do actually? can you update your question clearly

Comment: You need to either use multi dex or progaurd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio ONLY! DexException: Cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093664/android-studio-only-dexexception-cannot-merge-new-index-65536-into-a-non-jumbo)

Comment: @MujammilAhamed How to use...please help me

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/5515371

Comment: @MujammilAhamed i have lot of activities. where i use this MultiDex.install(this);

Comment: It's clearly mentioned in the sample to Mention it in Application class

Comment: @MujammilAhamed Sucess Thank you so much